# Telerik Report Designer - How to Remove Blank Lines From Data Source Value?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

Just started out using Telerik Report Designer.

My data source value 'fields.CUSTOMER_CustomerAddress' produces blank lines on my report and cannot for the life of me work out how to close/remove these when null.

How my Report looks:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgaTb.jpg

My Telerik interface

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50zbD.jpg

I tried putting my text box and data source value within a panel as someone else had mentioned ([Telerik Report Designer - Remove line if the parameter is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844521/telerik-report-designer-remove-line-if-the-parameter-is-null))

but I couldn't get this method to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to make the textbox invisible if the value is null.Please have a look at the images attached.

1. Right click on the textbox

[image]

2. New Rule

[image]

3. write expression

[image]

4. style

[image]

Comment: it should probably be stated that this will likely NOT work. you have to go into the properties grid for the control, then scaffold conditional formatting, then look for style, then toggle visibility off and on. Even if the default value is what you want. Basically if the value is not bold (visibility value will show bold after its been changed), it will get ignored.